# Excel Different line graph loaded on each selection

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2011

I have been adding a lot of absence/presence data into an MS Excel 2011 for Mac sheet. On the days students are present they get points, on days they are absent they get zero. If student was there, but no marks were given that day I add P for presence. I have one row per student and one column per class day:

```
Name:        D1 D2 D3
Student One  15 0  28
Student Two  12 14 16
Student 3    15 13 P
```

When I select this entire block with all data to create a line graph I get only one line. I need a line per student. When I select all data except for the labels `name` and `Dx` I sometimes get data shown for one student, sometimes I get separate lines per student which I want. How can I make sure I will get a line graph per student and all lines in one chart with the y-axis for marks and the x-axis for students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the "P" for present. If you take that out and leave that cell blank, you should be OK.

To then get Students on the X axis, you can either:

1. right-click on the chart, select "Select Data" and then click "Switch Row/Column", or
2. transpose your data set so you have Students along the top and classes along the bottom

Comment: I just tried that. I do get separate lines called series 1,2,3 and so on, but students on the x-axis and marks on the y-axis. I need each graph to show the students marks per day. So I need to reverse the axis I guess. How do I do that?

Comment: Updated to tell you how to transpose the graph